# Big table with both height and angle adjustable?

Tags: table, product-recommendation

I need a table for using laptop computer with external display and also working on graphic design on paper and computer, and handheld devices. I'm thinking I need a reasonable large table with both the height and the angle of the table top adjustable.

I've found this product: 
[https://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-Sit-Stand-Tilting-Adjustable-Angle/dp/B07PZKFFB3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PZKFFB3)

But it is too small to also sometimes have my paper draft laid out.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Look for a "drafting table". I happen to like the vintage ones, but there are more functional varieties with shelves, drawers etc. as well.

[image]

Just a suggestion to help the planet: LOTs of people have been giving these things away for free or dirt cheap because companies don't do mechanical drafting any more and they take up a lot of space, so check out your favorite on-line resources (like Craigslist, Nextdoor etc.) before shelling out a lot of money.

Comment: When it is adjusted to horizontal, is it at a height suitable for writing while sitting in a normal chair?

Comment: Depends on the height of the chair... i.e. define "normal". Also depends on the desk design.